# cordova - remove unnecessary permissions

Tags: android, cordova, android-permissions

I need to play sounds in my game, so I added org.apache.cordova.media plugin to my application. Now platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml contains 2 entries I don't need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

If I remove those lines, this file regenerated and permissions are added again. What is correct way to remove these permissions? I use apache cordova 3.5.0

Comment: Can you check the www>config.xml and look at the "<feature>" part. Maybe one of these features include the ones yo want to remove

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to open `plugins/android.json`, locate in that file part which looks like

```
"AndroidManifest.xml": {
     "parents": {
         "/*": [
......
{
      "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS\" />",
       "count": 1
},
......
{
      "xml": "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO\" />",
       "count": 1
},
......
],
```

and remove these files. After removal of that lines, make sure that `android.json` still be valid JSON file.
Also please notice the `count` property which indicates how many plugins use the permissions. If you have value more then 1 you should find which other plugins could use that permission. Also I don't sure that Cordova plugins was tested to be workable without proper permissions, so you on your own when removing permissions from that file.

If you put your system in the broken state, you always could remove all content of platforms and plugins folders and recreate your project by running

```
cordova create ...
cordova platform add ...
cordova plugin add ...
```

Answer (score 21):

Create a file in root directory of your project and rename it to **remove_permissions.js** then put the following code into it:

```
var permissionsToRemove = [ "RECORD_AUDIO", "MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var rootdir = "";
var manifestFile = path.join(rootdir, "platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml");

fs.readFile( manifestFile, "utf8", function( err, data )
{
    if (err)
        return console.log( err );

    var result = data;
    for (var i=0; i<permissionsToRemove.length; i++)
        result = result.replace( "<uses-permission android:name=\"android.permission." + permissionsToRemove[i] + "\" />", "" );

    fs.writeFile( manifestFile, result, "utf8", function( err )
    {
        if (err)
            return console.log( err );
    } );
} );
```

Open **config.xml** and add the bellow line in Android part:

```
<platform name="android">
...
     <hook type="after_prepare" src="remove_permissions.js"/>
...
</platform>
```

Now rebuild APK file.

Comment: In higher cordova verions the location of the AndroidManifest.xml file has changed to platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml otherwise it is a nice approach.

Comment: I had to change the path of the AndroidManifest.xml in the script to "platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", then it worked!!!

Comment: for the record, there seems to be an extra space in the closing xml tag, on the replace function. In my case I had to use `...permissionsToRemove[i] + "\"/>", "" );`

Answer (score 1):

The approach in @codevision's response used to work for me, but in more recent (I don't know exactly what cutoff) versions of the cordova-android platform, I found that permissions were still being merged into the final AndroidManifest.xml in the APK.

The cause of this was the [Merge Multiple Manifest Files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) build step that caused permissions declared from various plugin dependencies (including .aar files) to sneak back into the final AndroidManifest.xml.

What worked for me was creating an after-prepare script that modified `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

1. Add the following namespace declaration to the top-level `<manifest>` tag `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`
2. (Read carefully) Ensure that all the permissions that you *don't* want are present, but mark them with the attribute `tools:node="remove"`, e.g.:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" tools:node="remove">`

This prevents any dependencies from sneaking their `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission into the final APK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @SaeedHosseinPoor works, but the script is a bit brittle because it doesn't use an XML parser. Here's an alternative hook script that does. Tested on Node 15, Cordova 10, cordova-android 9.

1. Create `scripts/remove_permissions.js` with this content:

```
const fs = require('fs/promises')
const xml2js = require('xml2js')

const REMOVE_PERMISSIONS = [
  'android.permission.INTERNET',
  'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE',
]

module.exports = async function(context) {
  const root = context.opts.projectRoot
  const manifestPath = root + '/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
  const manifestXml = await fs.readFile(manifestPath)
  const manifest = await xml2js.parseStringPromise(manifestXml)
  const usesPermissions = manifest.manifest['uses-permission']
  if (Array.isArray(usesPermissions)) {
    manifest.manifest['uses-permission'] = usesPermissions.filter(usesPermission => {
      const attrs = usesPermission.$ || {}
      const name = attrs['android:name'] // Assuming xmlns:android has been set as usual...
      if (REMOVE_PERMISSIONS.includes(name)) {
        console.log(`Removing permission "${name}" from AndroidManifest.xml`)
        return false
      } else {
        return true
      }
    })
  }
  const newManifest = (new xml2js.Builder()).buildObject(manifest)
  await fs.writeFile(manifestPath, newManifest)
}
```

2. Run `npm add --save-dev xml2js`.
3. Add the hook to `config.xml`:

```
  <platform name="android">
    ...
    <hook type="after_prepare" src="scripts/remove_permissions.js"/>
  </platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer above but the manifest file kept getting re-generated.
I solved the problem by creating an "after_prepare" hook that modifies the manifest file during the build.

The code is posted on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42182147/7353847).