# How to remove unnecessary uses permission from android platform build?

Tags: cordova, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've developed a Cordova cross platform mobile app and within that built two packages for Android and IOS.

But during a security scan it was identified that 3 unecessary uses permissions existed in the Android platform's AndroidManifest.xml file.

The following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

In order to remediate this I deleted the permissions from the AndroidManifest file, then re-build the platform folders through a Jenkins build. But after every build the permissions reappear in the manifest file in the android platform folder.

**Question:**

How can you remove unnecessary uses permission from android platform build? 
Maybe the permission could be set to false in the Cordova config.xml file.

This is the file structure of the project:

lvl1: root Cordova folder
[image]

lvl 2: platforms folder

[image]

lvl 3: android platform folder

[image]

Comment: This seems to be plugin related. Unless you find the plugin that inserts these permissions, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: I'm going to try this fix which suggests removing form the cordova.media plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056149/cordova-adds-unwanted-permission-to-androidmanifest-xml-when-building-from-cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extra permissions are added by Cordova plugins. Check out plugin.xml  file in each plugin folder and find out which plugin adds this permission.

If those plugins are not required, you can remove them else you may have to retain the permissions to make those plugins work. For instance, to use Cordova file plugin you require read/write permission to external storage.

Answer (score 3):

Deleting the permissions from the AndroidManifest.xml file will not remove it, because during each build the lines which u delegate will again be copied from the respective plugins.

**To Remove this lines**

[image]

1. open the plugins folder
2. Open a particular plugin, eg. filepath
3. Inside that plugin open its plugin.xml file in a notepad
4. Now comment the lines as shown in the below image

[image]

5. After this when you build, the lines will not show up on AndroidManifest.xml file
6. Do this for all the plugins which has those lines.