# I am running a barcode scanner as well as a qr code scanner but I get an XML duplication error while trying to build to my device

Tags: android, angular, xml, typescript, ionic-framework

Here is my TS code where StartScannig() is used to start the qrscanner and Scan() is for the barcode scanner.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { QRScanner , QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner/ngx';
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs/ngx';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular/';
import { ScannerLogicService } from '../services/scanner-logic.service';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-screen',
  templateUrl: './home-screen.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-screen.page.scss'],
})
export class HomeScreenPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public dialog: Dialogs, public qr: QRScanner, private myService: ScannerLogicService,
              public barcode: BarcodeScanner) {
    this.boolHasMask = false;

    // Disable scanning when back button is pressed
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.opacity = '1';
      this.qrScan.unsubscribe();

      // Set the date string
      this.todayDate = new Date();
      this.dd = String(this.todayDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
      this.mm = String(this.todayDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); // January is 0!
      this.yyyy = String(this.todayDate.getFullYear());
      this.dateString = this.mm + '/' + this.dd + '/' + this.yyyy;
    });


  }
  qrScan: any; // Used to set the instance of the QRscanner

  // variables needed for the interface before sending it to the database
  qrString: any; // Used to get the string of the qr code that is scanned
  // childTemp: string;
  boolHasMask: boolean; // variable used to determine if a mask is given away or not

  // Setting the date
  todayDate: Date;
  dd: string;
  mm: string;
  yyyy: string;
  dateString;

  StartScanning() {
    this.qr.prepare().then((status: QRScannerStatus) => { // request permission to use the scanner
      if (status.authorized){
          this.qr.show();
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.opacity = '0';
          this.qrScan = this.qr.scan().subscribe((textFound) => {
           document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.opacity = '1';
           document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.opacity = '1';
           this.qrScan.unsubscribe();
           // this.dialog.alert(textFound);
           this.myService.childQRID = textFound;
           this.qr.destroy();
           this.qrScan().unsubscribe();
            }, (err) => {
              this.dialog.alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            });
      }
      else if (status.denied){
        this.dialog.alert('Please allow camera access to scan');
      }
      else{
        this.dialog.alert('Something went wrong...');
      }
    });

     // Die maak seker dat die qr scanner nie aanhoudend run nie.
    document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: any) => {
        ev.detail.register(10, () => {
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.opacity = '1';
        document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.opacity = '1';
        this.qr.destroy();
        this.qrScan().unsubscribe();

      });
    });
  }

  // Once the confirm button has been pressed confirm all the variables into the service
  Confirm() {
    // this.myService.childQRID = this.qrString;
    const date = new Date();
    this.myService.scanDate = date;
    this.myService.hasMask = this.boolHasMask;

    // Edited out because it is only used for testing
    /* console.log(this.myService.childQRID);
    console.log(this.myService.temperature);
    console.log(this.myService.scanDate);
    console.log(this.myService.hasMask); */

    // test data Dialog
    // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
    this.dialog.alert('QR ID: ' + this.myService.childQRID + '\r\n'
      + 'Temperature: ' + this.myService.temperature + ' ℃' + '\r\n'
      + 'Date of Scan: ' + this.myService.scanDate + '\r\n'
      + 'Has Mask: ' + this.myService.hasMask);

    /** Send All values to the API using this space */
    // Clear values after set() to the API
    this.myService.childQRID = null;
    this.myService.temperature = null;
    this.myService.scanDate = null;
    this.myService.hasMask = false;
    this.boolHasMask = false;


  }

  // The scan() method is used to scan the barcodes of people's ID's
  Scan() { 
    this.barcode.scan().then((barcodeData) => { 
      alert(barcodeData.text)
    }, (err) => { 
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
  }
```

Below would be the error I received when trying to build to android:

```
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-65 Error:
        Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-65 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-90
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-84 Error:
        Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-84 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-85
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

22 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 21 up-to-date
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-65 Error:
        Element uses-permission#android.permission.CAMERA at AndroidManifest.xml:18:5-65 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:15:5-90
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-84 Error:
        Element uses-feature#android.hardware.camera at AndroidManifest.xml:20:5-84 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-85
C:\Scanner_App\SmartScan_App\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        Validation failed, exiting

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

It seems that the problem lies with both packages requiring camera access to work. Is there a way for both to gain access to the camera or even better yet scan both qr- and barcodes?
I have tried removing the duplicates in the below XML code but it gave the same error. It might rewrite the xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems importing both
{ QRScanner , QRScannerStatus } from '@ionic-native/qr-scanner/ngx';
&
{ BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';
was the issue. The BarcodeScanner has a built in qr-code scanner which clashed when their plugin.xml files merged with the AndroidManifest.xml file. So only using the BarcodeScanner was fine for scanning both.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your manifest code again, you have doubles there.

This two are doubles.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false" />
```

And this two are doubles

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: When I remove the duplicates it is added again automatically when I run ionic cordova run android

Comment: I am not familiar with ionic cordova run, but i found some threads about automatically adding permissions using ionic cordova. Can you please check this thread, maybe it can help you out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062877/13481732

Comment: Also check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510751/cordova-android-duplicated-uses-feature-from-two-plugins, it looks like it is the same problem as yours.